# How do I go about writing a windows driver for a bluetooth device?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, mouse, driver, multi-touch

I am looking for some advice/input on **writing a device driver**.  I have never written one for windows before, let alone for bluetooth.

Can you **recommend a book** or website or something to get me started?  I have the windows driver kit, and the examples therein but with out some place to start I am dead in the water.

*The specifics*:  My friend gave me his mac Magic Mouse.  I have a windows 7 machine. With the mouse set up as just a generic HID device it works ok as a two button mouse with no scroll, the motion is smooth and the acceleration what you expect in a windows mouse.

The mouse actually has a fairly good lpi resolution, making it pretty sensitive.  There are mac drivers available, extracted from bootcamp.  They kind of work.  The cursor will randomly freeze or stop responding to the mouse's movement, which is buffered, and then leap once whatever has caused the stall stops.  As an added touch the mac drivers make the cursor move like it would on a mac, with that logarithmic acceleration, that will completely throw off any windows user.  With the driers you get vertical and horizontal scroll, but that's it.  There is no multi touch functionality, and you can't change any of the behaviors, like acceleration.  There isn't multiclutch for windows, or other 3rd party software for a multi touch mouse.

So I figured I would endeavor to make my own drivers and multi touch functionality in windows for this thing.  I know mac will never support it properly under windows and windows won't write there own drivers until there is a reason.

Also if any one knows of any one else trying to do the same or similar things, point me to them.

Comment: I suspect that one doesn't write a Bluetooth driver for this task but just a driver that gets involved in the HID stream.  I'd suggesting asking again at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/threads